# Bias in forward stepwise selection in regression

Tags: regression, subset

Let $Y=X\beta+E$ be a linear model with p variables and suppose that we perform som subset selection and we only use k variables where $k<p$.

I want to get the biase os the new model.

I call $X=(X_1,X_2)$ the X mattrix where $X_1$ include all the k variables an $X_2$ include the $p-k$ variables not used in the model. So I can express the model as $Y=(X_1,X_2)(\beta_1, \beta_2)+E$.

The model with only k variables whould be $Y=(X_1,0)(\beta_1, 0)+E$ and I want to get the biase of the new model.

$\hat{\beta}=(X_1',X_1)^{-1}X'_1Y$, so $E[\hat{\beta}]=E[(X_1',X_1)^{-1}X'_1Y]=E[(X_1',X_1)^{-1}X'_1((X_1,X_2)(\beta_1,\beta_1)+E)]$ so, becouse $E[E]=0$, I get that $E[\hat{\beta}]=\beta_1+(X_1',X_1)^{-1}X'_1X_2\beta_2$

Is it correct?

Comment: I believe you are ignoring that these are not too previously picked subsets of parameters, but are instead picked in a data dependant manner depending on the size of $\hat{\beta}_i/\text {SE}(\hat{\beta}_i)$.

Comment: So, the biase I calculated is the biase if I chose de k variable randomly but I chose the variables with a criteria so the biase I calculated is incorect?

Comment: In this case, how can I stimate the biase?